# Oracle materialized view setting

Tags: database, oracle, materialized-views

I have an Oracle (Oracle Database 11g - 11.2.0.3.0) that uses a materialized view to connect to other Oracle databases.  The materialized view seems to have mapped the field of type NUMBER to a byte(3).  Now that there are larger values (x,000s) versus (x00s) in the associated database, the refresh is failing since it is too large to fit.  I've tried recompiling and altering the size of the column, but it complains with errors.  The original SQL does not appear to specify the column sizes - simple field selects into the mview.

```
Issue: ORA-12899: value too large for column "XXXXX"."YYYY_MV"."ZZZZZ" (actual: 4, maximum: 3)
```

A. Recompiling

```
ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW XXXXX.YYYY_MV COMPILE

VIEW CUSTOMERS.CHAMP_DSS_CUSTOMERS_MV altered.
```

(but still fails to run refresh).

B. Altering

```
ALTER:
  [sqltask] alter materialized view XXXXX.YYYY_MV
  [sqltask]     modify (ZZZZZ CHAR(30 BYTE))
  [sqltask] Exception executing sql java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01732: data manipulation operation not legal on this view
```

Has anyone run into this behavior, what is your suggested fix/exit strategy?

Comment: That error message doesn't seem to match the statement.  I wonder if the tool you're using for the statement is interfering with it in some way, or running it in the wrong context.  Could you try running the statement in SQL\*Plus?  I know SQL\*Plus is not always convenient, but it's useful for situations like this, to ensure the commands are getting executed exactly the way you want.

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide the table definition and materialized view table definition, after verifying you are seeing the same issue using SQL Plus as @JonHeller suggested?  I doubt that a materialized view would/could map a `NUMBER` field as a `CHAR` type